# How to write a header in the top of grid container with two or more grids

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have a couple of grid containers where I have a grids inside them with different number of grids , I am trying to write a header in the top middle of the grids but it appears in different place every time 
Here is my code for HTML :

```
    <div className="grid-container">

      <div className="logo">
        <img  className="logo-img"src={require('../images/kcal.jpeg')} alt='logo'/>
        <p className="logo-text">Find out your recommended calories requirement for the day with the Calorie Calculator.</p>

       </div>

      <div className="gender"> 
      <h3 className="genderQues">What is your gender?</h3>
      <div className="maleBox">
      <img src={require("../images/male.jpg")} alt="male"/>
      <h4>Male</h4>
      <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender"  onChange={this.radioButtons} />
      </div>
      <div className='femaleBox'>
      <img src={require("../images/female.jpg")} alt="female"/>
      <h4>Female</h4>
      <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender"  onChange={this.radioButtons}/> 
      </div>
      </div>





      <div className="height" id="heightForm"> 
            <h3 className="heightQues">What is your height?</h3>
            <div className="heightBox">
            <img src={require('../images/height.png')} alt="height" />
            <input type="input" id="heightText" name="height"  onChange={this.textBoxes} /> 
            <label>CM</label>

            </div>



      </div>
<div className="activity">
      <h3 className="activityQues">Which best describes your daily activity level?</h3>

        <div className="lowBox">
        <img src={require("../images/sitting.jpg")} alt="low activity"/>
        <h4>I engage in light physical activities</h4>
        <p>eg. office worker; taxi driver, with no exercising days</p>
      <input type="radio" id="Low" name="activity"  onChange={this.radioButtons}/>  
      </div> 
      <div className="mediumBox">
      <img src={require("../images/running.jpg")} alt="low activity"/>
      <h4>I engage in moderate physical activities</h4>
      <p>eg. walking briskly, slow leisure cycling, leisure swimming ,tablet tennis, golf, tai chi, or jogging.</p>
       <input type="radio" id="Medium" name="activity"  onChange={this.radioButtons}/>   
       </div>    
       <div className="highBox">
       <img src={require("../images/lifting.jpg")} alt="high activity"/>
       <h4>I engage in vigorous physical activities</h4>
       <p>eg. aerobics, or soccer, liffting, basketball, lap swimming or other competitive sports.</p>
      <input type="radio"  id="High" name="activity"  onChange={this.radioButtons}/> 
      </div>
       </div>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
.logo {
  display: grid;
  width: 65%;
  height:150px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: honeydew;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
}

.logo-text{
  text-align: right;
}
.gender {
    display: grid;
    width: 60%;
    height:450px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 350px);
    grid-gap: 80px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "a  b";
    background-color: honeydew;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: auto;

  }
  .maleBox{
      grid-area: a;
      height: 90%;
      padding:20px;
      margin-left: auto;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 25px;
      background: rgb(120, 236, 105);
      width: 200px;
  }
  .femaleBox{
      grid-area: b;
      padding:20px;
      height:90%;
      margin-right: auto;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 25px;
      background: rgb(120, 236, 105);
      width: 200px;
  }

.activity {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,120px);
    grid-gap:150px;
    grid-template-areas:"a b c" ;
    width: 60%;
    height:650px;
    background-color: honeydew;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

  .lowBox{
    grid-area: a;
    height: 90%;
    padding:20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: rgb(120, 236, 105);
    width: 200px;



  }
  .mediumBox{
    grid-area: b;
  height: 90%;
  padding:20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: rgb(120, 236, 105);
  width: 200px;


  }
  .highBox{
    grid-area: c;
    height: 90%;
    padding:20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: rgb(120, 236, 105);
    width: 200px;


  }
  .heightBox{
    padding:10px;
    height: 400px;
    margin:5px;
    margin:auto;
    justify-self: right;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    text-align: center;
    width: 450px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: rgb(120, 236, 105);

  }
h3{
  text-align: center;
}
```

This is what appears [![I want this to be beside the Picture but it appears in the other grid 
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gjnX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gjnX.png)

[image: Here I want the question to be above the grids in the middle but it appears downward the grids[![][2]]

can anyone help me with this ?